# Using MessageDigest with J2ME Application

Tags: java, java-me, sha

I'm unable to use the `MessageDigest` API in a J2ME application - it is giving ALERT **NoSuchMethodError**

> digest()

My code is

```
MessageDigest md= MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");         
md.update(hashString.getBytes("UTF-8"),0,0);
byte[] digest = null;
md.digest(digest,0,digest.length);
System.out.println("digest of str is "+new String(digest) );
```

The above code works fine in a Java application, but gives `NoSuchMethodError` in J2ME.

Can I use `MessageDigest` in J2ME?  If **yes**, please tell me how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[java.security.MessageDigest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) is not generally part of J2ME, so it's not directly available.

There are *some* J2ME devices that implement [JSR 177](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=177), which would allow you to use `MessageDigest`.

Or, you could try an open source SHA1 implementation, [such as this one](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/tutorials/ws-soa-securesoap2/section7.html#listing23).

Another alternative would be to use the [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) library, and [use it to implement SHA1 digests for J2ME](http://myprogramminglab.blogspot.com/2010/01/java-bouncycastle-sha-1.html).

If you use BouncyCastle, make sure to get one of the releases (.jar or source code) [that's designed for J2ME](http://www.bouncycastle.org/download/lcrypto-j2me-149.zip).